# Can I transfer a Google Drive's credit to another Google account?

Tags: google-drive, google-one

As a freelancer, I signed up for a Google Drive 200 Gb. subscription for a project where I had to exchange a large amount of files with my client. Now we have decided to stop our relationship. I managed to get my client to pay for the subscription, since I wouldn't have signed up if it wasn't for this project, but now he wants me to hand over to him the Google Drive in question.

The problem: I opened that Google Drive using my trademark (the Google login is "my-trademark"@gmail.com), and I don't really want him to use a Google account that has my business name. Is there a way I can transfer my Google credit to his Google account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cancel or downgrade a Drive storage plan

Source: [support.google.com/drive/answer/6374282](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6374282#zippy=%2Ccancel-or-downgrade-a-drive-storage-plan%2Ccancel-or-downgrade-storage-on-your-google-one-membership)

1. Google Drive Plans are **non-refundable**
2. Google Drive Plans are **not transferable** ([cancel or downgrade](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6374282#zippy=%2Ccancel-or-downgrade-a-drive-storage-plan%2Ccancel-or-downgrade-storage-on-your-google-one-membership))
3. You can  **cancel/downgrade at any time** and that will take effect at the start of the next billing cycle.

It is worth noting that

1. **you did not open a Google Drive account** using your trademark (as you phrased it);
2. **you did create a Google account** using your trademark;
3. **Google accounts give you Google-wide access** to most Google products including Google Ads, Gmail, YouTube, Gmail, Calendar, Charts, Drive, Sheets, Slides, Drawings, Forms, Jamboard, Translate and a [multitude of other Google products and services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_products);
4. **to login** to any Google product, **you must use a Google Account**.;
5. if you don't have a Google account, Google will take you through the creation process;
6. outside of Google Workspace accounts, **Google drive like most offerings is not an asset** that exists sepperate from the Google account to which it is associated.
7. Whomsoever controls the Google Account, controls the Google Drive.

---

#### How to Proceed

Assuming you control the Google Account in question, your **personal** and **contractual** relationship with the client will inform how you proceed.

**Personal Considerations**
Your actual response will be based on the relationship you have with the client and your interest in maintaining it.  Given that the client cannot get a refund from Google, nor can they transfer the plan to themselves, the options should you be inclined to provide compensation are limited to options like:.

1. Financially compensate them.
   **You don't need** the storage, but **they can't use** the storage so that may affect the level of compensation you offer (i.e. share the financial pain in some way).
2. **Give them full access** to a shared folder in your Google Drive to do with as they please for the remainder of the term.
3. Offer another form of compensation, like a Compensate them, in

**Contractual Considerations**
That is something only you know based on agreements

---

#### $ ?!

Given that a 200GB Google Drive storage plan is USD $3/month or USD $30/year it is surprising that this is unresolved.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I knew that Google Drive accounts and Google accounts are one and the same, which is precisely why I don't want to hand over that account to my client.

Comment: As for our relationship... well, we haven't parted in good terms, which is one of the reasons why this hasn't been solved. I do have plans to compensate him with other unresolved issues, so I don't think that will be a problem.